# Font Awesome icons are not showing Impreza thme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I got a client and She was looking for a **WordPress** website. I took the project and started the project on my server. Yesterday I completed the project and transfer the whole website to my client main domain which is [gulugalmarketing.com](https://gulugalmarketing.com/).

Everything was working just fine on my server! but when I transferred the website I got an issue which is Font awesome icons are loading properly! AS you can see the website is showing a small square box instead of icons.

I tried to check out the console and it's giving the errors.

> "Access to Font at been blocked by CORS policy"

I did try t replace the HTTPS to HTTP by using a plugin which is "Better search replace" but no luck as my client is using SSL.

Can somebody check this issue out and let me know.

Comment: Looks like the font resources not found on the server

Comment: Yes i was missing this link <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

Comment: Make sure you have included fontawesome css into your site.

Answer (score 0):

Include Font awesome CSS link in your document file and then it works

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enqueue Font Awesome into your theme's function.php, like below:

```
// Load Font Awesome 
function enqueue_font_awesome() {

    // Font Awesome
    wp_enqueue_style ('fontawesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css');

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_font_awesome' );
```